# Commerce.js cart.line_items is not returning as an array at the start and is giving me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commerce.js

I am trying to find whether my cart is empty by using `const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;`, but it is returning Cannot read property length of undefined. So i console.logged whether cart.line_items is an array and it ends up returning false, true, true. So for some reason it isnt recognized as an array at the start. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this catch `if(!cart.line_items) return 'Loading...'` seemed to solve the problem